# Read three column and write two column in excel using selenium java

Tags: java

I need to read three columns as `Name`, `Empid` and `empcode` from excel, insert into textbox and save the record then `setid` & `reqid` fields are generated. Now save the `setid` and `reqid` after the `Name`,`Empid` and `empcode` in the same excel. I have tried any code from the internet but not much is working.

Below code for writing in excel

```
public static XSSFWorkbook wb;
public static XSSFSheet sheet;
public static FileInputStream fs;
public static FileOutputStream out;
public void WriteExcelFile()
{
     String str1 = ackgreqid1.getText();

        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/com/testdata/FreeTestData.xlsx");

        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            sheet = wb.getSheet("TestData");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("unable to find workbook or worksheet");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator<Row> sheetrow = sheet.rowIterator();
        // Row firstRow = sheetrow.next();
        // int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        // = firstRow.cellIterator();
        // Iterator<Cell> cell = firstRow.cellIterator();
        while (sheetrow.hasNext()) {
            Row value = sheetrow.next();
            // System.out.println(value);
            Iterator<Cell> cell = value.cellIterator();
            Cell cellValue = cell.next();
            String cellData = cellValue.getStringCellValue();
            while (cell.hasNext()) {
                if (cellData.equalsIgnoreCase("Step-Up")) {
                    int lastCellNum = value.getLastCellNum();
                    // System.out.println(lastCellNum);
                    Cell createCell = value.createCell(lastCellNum);
                    createCell.setCellValue(str1);
                    try {
                        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        wb.write(out);
                        // cell.next();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            out.close();
                            break;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: You can't handle excel with Selenium. Post the code you tries and explain what was the problem with it.

Comment: Its web application, screen is of excel. @Hasitha

Comment: Any error you got? What is `Step-Up`? And what about the reading part? Does that read successfully?

Comment: Step-up is column name, reading is working